# How to add google adsense code in opencart project without using extension?

Tags: opencart, adsense

I am trying with module but it doesn't work. how to add in pages. I am new to `opencart`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to that specific page, should be found under `Catalog > View > Theme > {page you looking for)`. Check within the code for the section you would like to add it to and paste it in. 
**Remember to backup the files before you make changes to the core files.**