# I have bug in displaying ads on my website. Website build with opencart 3

Tags: adsense, opencart-3

I have a bug in displaying ads on my website, ads not displaying. The website builds with Opencart 3. Where to paste google Adsense code.

Comment: what did you do so far?

Comment: i followed this link-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443220/how-to-add-google-adsense-code-in-opencart-project-without-using-extension?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place your Ads on Opencart 3X Follow this procedure

1. Go to Extensions/Extension
2. Select Modules from the list
3. Add HTML Content module
4. Fill all the required fields and Paste Your Adsense Code in description section by enabling code view.

Now go to Design/Layout chose your Layout where your Ads should be displayed
Select the position of the module.

Hope this might Help you

Comment: can I see screenshots if possible

Comment: screen shots given in answer

Comment: @AmitModi everything looks fine... Is Adsense approved for your site?

Comment: yes,I am using infolink for ads.i got mail about approval .

Comment: you asked the question regarding Google Adsense am I right?

Comment: I tested Google Adsense on my website... and it works perfectly

Comment: there is no code in right column see <aside id="column-right" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
    <div>  <p><br></p></div>

  </aside>

Comment: i am not know about this .what menas u.

Comment: tell me more about opencart.